# Ways to define and use partially bound functions

Tags: python

The two ways I'm aware of to have a partially-bound function that can be later called is:

```
apply_twice = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(x))
square2x = apply_twice(lambda x: x*x)
square2x(2)
# 16
```

And

```
def apply_twice(f):
    def apply(x):
        return f(f(x))
    return apply

square_2x=apply_twice(lambda x: x*x)
square_2x(4)
# 256
```

Are there any other common ways to pass around or use partially-bound functions?

Comment: This isn't really partial binding, assuming you mean *partial application*. Partial application, of say, `def foo(a, b, c): ...` would be something like `partial_foo = lambda a, b: foo(a, b, 42)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga When you say this isn't really partial binding, do you mean because both versions of `apply_twice` are curried?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no, I mean because both functions have the same arity, and do different things besides. And this isn't currying, I'm pretty sure. Currying is when you decompose a multiple-argument function into various, single-arity functions. So for `lambda a, b, c: return a + b + c` a curried version would be `lambda a: lambda b: lambda c: return a + b + c` it's a distinct though similar concept as partial applicaitoin

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's what I mean. Both versions of `apply_twice()` in the OP are already curried.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean, in the sense that *all 1-arity* functions are *already* curried? But  that's not what I mean. I mean it isn't partial application because a function isn't being created with a lower arity, that does the same thing. That is what partial application means. The above is just fun with higher-order funcitons

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I think I understand what you are saying. Both `apply_twice()` and `square2x()` are 1-arity in both examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) can be used to partially apply an ordinary Python function. This is especially useful if you already have a regular function and want to apply only some of the arguments.

```
from functools import partial

def apply_twice(f, x):
    return f(f(x))

square2x = partial(apply_twice, lambda x: x*x)
print(square2x(4))
```

It's also important to remember that functions are only one type of callable in Python, and we're free to define callables ourselves as ordinary user-defined classes. So if you have some complex operation that you want to behave like a function, you can always write a class, which lets you document in more detail what it is and what the different parts mean.

```
class MyApplyTwice:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.f(self.f(x))

square2x = MyApplyTwice(lambda x: x*x)
print(square2x(4))
```

While overly verbose in this example, it can be helpful to write your function out as a class if it's going to be storing state long-term or might be doing confusing mutable things with its state. It's also useful to keep in mind for learning purposes, as it's a healthy reminder that closures and objects are two sides of the same coin. They're really the same thing, viewed in a different light.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
def apply_twice(f, x):
    return f(f(x))

square_2x = functools.partial(apply_twice, lambda x: x*x)
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really partial binding, assuming you mean *partial application*.

Partial application is when you create a function that does the same thing as another function by fixing some number of its arguments, producing a function of smaller arity (the arity of a function is the number of arugments it takes).

So, for example,

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

A partially applied version of foo would be something like:

```
def partial_foo(a, b):
    return foo(a, b, 42)
```

Or, with a lambda expression:

```
partial_foo = lambda a, b: foo(a, b, 42)
```

However, note, the above goes against the official style guidelines, in PEP8, you shouldn't assign the result of lambda expressions to a name, if you are going to do that just use a full function defintion.

The module, `functools`, has a helper for partial application:

```
import functools
partial_foo = functools.partial(foo, c=42)
```

Note, you may have heard about "currying", which sometimes gets confused for partial application. Currying is when you decompose a n-arity function into N, 1-arity functions. So, more concretely, for `foo`:

```
curried_foo = lambda a: lambda b: lambda c: a + b + c
```

Or in long form:

```
def curried_foo(a):
    def _curr0(b):
        def _curr1(c):
            return a + b + c
        return _curr1
    return _curr0
```

And the important part, `curried_foo(1)(2)(3) == foo(1, 2, 3)`